# PR review comment position

Tags: github, position, pull-request, git-diff

When I get the `position` of a code review comment at GitHub it returns an index from the `diff` according to [API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#get-a-single-comment), but I cannot map that `diff` index to the original file line. Anybody with relevant experience, please help.

Answer (score 0):

The response also includes an `original_position` field which should have the line number in the original file.

Keep in mind that these are positions within the diff, and not offsets from the beginning of the file.  You can find offsets for the diff hunk itself within the file in the `diff_hunk` field.  The position does not reset between hunks, so the sum of sizes of preceding hunks needs to be subtracted from `position` to obtain a line offset within the relevant hunk.

There's some documentation on the relationship between `position` and line in the file [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#input):

> The position value is the number of lines down from the first "@@" hunk header in the file... The line just below the "@@" line is position 1, the next line is position 2, and so on. The position in the file's diff continues to increase through lines of whitespace and additional hunks until a new file is reached.

Comment: I checked that as well, but that is also another index and often set to to 0.

Comment: The positions should be within the relevant diff hunk.  Edited for clarification.

Comment: OK. Can you please help me understand how the position could be 140? I can see the comment--"I'm not sure why this is showing up in the diff -- did you move it?" between these two hunks--'@@ -1521,16 +1576,6 @@' and '@@ -1540,8 +1585,8 @@' of dygraph.js at github.com/danvk/dygraphs/pull/296/files . The api can be accessed from here: https://api.github.com/repos/danvk/dygraphs/pulls/296/comments

Comment: The position doesn't reset to zero between hunks.  I've updated with some additional explanation.

Comment: OK, thanks. But, I am getting instance position=0, what does that mean? According to DOC, the position should be never 0, right?

Comment: Hmm... I've seen `null`, but not `0`.  Would that be just _above_ the first line?